# HTML Forms Array Submission Simulation

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to mockup a simple HTML form that simulates an HTTP POST from an external party. When I look at the POST data coming in it looks like this:

```
array (
  'submission_id' => '1234567890',
  'name' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Bart',
    1 => 'Simpson',
  ),
  'address' => 
  array (
    0 => '1000 Springfield Road',
    1 => 'Level 2',
    2 => 'Los Angeles',
    3 => 'CA',
    4 => '90210',
    5 => '',
  ),
  'date' => 
  array (
    0 => '05',
    1 => '01',
    2 => '2017',
  ),
```

I'm trying to simulate a simple HTML form with inputs but haven't worked with arrays before so not sure of the syntax. For example for the 'name' would it be:

```html
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did need to use the [] syntax to get the numbered arrays:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

using the same name attribute should result in the array in the form post

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: In my testing I did need to use the [] syntax to get the numbered array